# joomla onContentBeforeSave .. keep adding readmore div to text

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

Trying to make same changes to article using a plugin just before saving.
Joomla! keep adding readmore div to text.

```
class PlgContentEditArti extends JPlugin
{
    function onContentBeforeSave($context, $article, $isNew)
    {
        if($context == "com_content.article")
        {   
        $article->fulltext = "hi";

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Output

```
<hr id="system-readmore" />
<p>hi</p>
```

Comment: its <hr id="system-readmore" />
<p>hi</p>

Comment: Joomla! is not adding readmore div, but your code is **only** changing the article `fulltext` which is after the `introtext` that separated by `readmore`. If you have an empty `introtext` then that output is correct. What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: thank you .. I am trying to...
check the article for images before saving it .....
check if image are external .......
if true save image to server and modify src .....
Save the article and print message to author of the article...